# Ожидание отвата на сообщение discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord

Я бы хотел, чтобы после отправки сообщения в лс бот давал 3 минуты на отправку следующего и из этого собирал Embed. Как мне это сделать? я умею ловить сообщения в лс, умею собирать Embed, но не могу сделать ожидание. Помогите мне пожалуйста.

Comment: [Тут](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages) все в подробностях описано.

Comment: просидев за этим делом пол миллиона лет, я добился лишт вот этого:  https://pastebin.com/bFjNij5H, но я не смог сделать сохранение сообщений, чтобы х куда-то отправить.